# Detecting element in viewport does not work on mobile safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, mobile-safari

I use the **Simple Utility Function** from [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/488073/5779171) to detect if a element is in my viewport. If it is, an fade-in animation is started for my content.

**It works fine on Windows, macOS, Android** and every browser on iOS **except for Safari**. In Safari the content stays hidden and the animation only **starts after I try to zoom out** of my site. I tested this on iOS 10 and 11 Beta 5.

My solution to this problem would be detecting if the user uses Safari on iOS and don't animate my content. But i would like to fix this problem so that the animation works. Can anyone help me with this?

**EDIT:** I think the issue is caused by Semantic-ui.Tested it with plain html and javascript and it works. I try to fix it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finnaly found a solution.

The issue was the **sidebar from Semantic UI**. I found a [CSS snipped](https://semantic-ui.com/modules/sidebar.html#ios-sidebars) on the docs. I altered the code a little bit and added it to my css file.

```
html.ios {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: auto !important;
}
html.ios,
html.ios body {
    height: initial !important;
}
```

Seems like [-webkit-overflow-scrolling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-overflow-scrolling) caused the problem. But i had to add the other lines of code too or else it stutters when i scroll.

Like this, everything works perfectly!